# Viewing the DNS cache in the Server Manager

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I usually look at the DNS cahce via the commandline "ipconfig/displaydns"

Someone told me the other day "you can just look it up in the Server Manager window".

I've tried and I've searched, but I can find how to view the cache here.

Is this possible, or was the person speaking of something entirly different, like an MMC snap-in?

Comment: ipconfig/displaydns shows the DNS client cache, not the DNS server cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to see DNS Server cache. Open DNS Server MMC and Click on your server. Click on View option.  Advanced Option Click that.

You can see Cached Lookup option. You can check cached result from there.